If 1 ingress rule is having issue then entire application is going down in Azure
I have an application which is having multiple microservices and some ingress rules. When deployed this application in Azure a strange behaviour was observed when 1 of those ingress rule is having issue which is making the application inaccessible.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "86400"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - abc.myhost.com
      secretName: app-tls-secrets
  rules:
    - host: abc.myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /somepath
            backend:
              service:
                name: app1
                port:
                  number: 8080
            pathType: Prefix

I am following the above ingress structure to define all of my ingress configuration.
Observed is when the hostname is either FQDN(Fully Qualified Domain Name) or wildcard (*.myhost.com) for all ingress then only the app is accessible else (few having FQDN and few having wildcard) app is not available using Azure gateway.
Is this an expected behaviour from Azure.

Mixing FQDNs and wildcard hostnames in your Ingress rules may lead to conflicts. try using only FQDNs or only wildcard hostnames across all your Ingress rules. Else do one thing If you need to use both FQDNs and wildcard hostnames, define them in separate Ingress resources.

It is not expected behavior for Azure to make the entire application inaccessible when one ingress rule is having an issue. It is possible that there is an issue with the configuration of the ingress rules. Your observation is correct- Application Gateway uses hostname-based routing for directing traffic to the appropriate backend services. Ingress resources are consistent when we do not mix FQDN and wildcard hostnames. it may lead to routing issues and make the entire application inaccessible.
You can cross check your ingress configuration and application logs, verify the backend health to identify the issue and then redeploy the application and ingress.
Assuming you have already setup your aks, appgw and AGIC, below is an example-

Sample deployment and service
app1
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80


app2
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app2
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app2
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    app: app2
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80



ingress for app1
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "86400"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - abc.myhost.com
      secretName: app-tls-secrets
  rules:
    - host: abc.myhost.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /somepath
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app1
                port:
                  number: 8080



ingress for app2
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app2-ingress
  namespace: myapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/request-timeout: "86400"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - '*.myhost.com'
      secretName: wildcard-tls-secrets
  rules:
    - host: '*.myhost.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /anotherpath
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app2
                port:
                  number: 8080



Reference-

issues with Ingress Controller
AGIC on AKS
Azure AppGW


I see all my services and pods are running without any issue but still makes app inaccessible if we mixup the host names.
Can you share any docs/links that mentions below statement.
Ingress resources are consistent when we do not mix FQDN and wildcard hostnames. it may lead to routing issues and make the entire application inaccessible.
